# Data not easily accessible after converting pdf to .xls

Tags: microsoft-excel, pdf, vba, macros, conversion

[image: ScreenCapture]

This is what I get after converting pdf to excel format. Trying to figure out if there is a way for me to put this in a better format to pull the prices and make a table out of the data in the 1st and 3rd columns. I have tried text to column and it doesn't work properly. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a very difficult question to answer without seeing your original data and the resulting data, or knowing how you're converting.

Comment: What do you mean "*tried text to column and it doesn't work properly*"? What does it do? How are you converting it?

Comment: Can you share the input PDF?

Comment: There are multiple ways to get a PDF data into excel. Unfortunately, converting to .xls is not usually a good result. Try first if can convert to .csv.  There are other options if that does not work, but will need to know which version of office you have.